# Variable reference of both an interface and class type

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I am porting some code from objective-c and there they have a syntax which says
`SomeClass<SomeInterface> myVar = whatever;`

This means the object also handles the interface.
I am trying to figure out what to do with this in c#
The function in question must return an object of type SomeClass which can also perform the unrelated tasks defined in SomeInterface.

The only way I can think of doing this right now is to make a new interface that mimics SomeClass and extends SomeInterface. However this would mean adding a new interface for every combination of functionalities I come across.

Here is the use case that makes this useful.
SomeClass in my case is a class which can populate all its variables automatically from a data file. So this is a very generic class. Some interface is some specific functions it can do. So all I am saying is you must give me a class who can auto populate himself,and his job is XYZ(the interface)

Any suggestions?

Edit Just to clarify why you use this programing pattern, here is a easy to understand example

`Terminator class`
`Cylon class`

`Interface HumanityDestroyer`

`Some Factory class`-
`Terminator<HumanityDestroyer> BuildTerminator();`

So in this example the factory is putting together 2 things that don't have to be related. Not all terminators are humanity destroyers. I can then somewhere else use the same thing but return a Cylon. I didn't have to add any extra interfaces to do this, but can be assured at compile time that it will do both jobs.

Based on the comments I believe in c# I just need to have separate interfaces for each "grouping" of "is" and "can-do" behavior.

Comment: Can you clarify: does this indicate that *all* `SomeClass` must implement `SomeInterface`? Or does it mean that it is limited to those `SomeClass` who also implement `SomeInterface` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, it sounds like you want to create a generic `SomeClass` class with a constraint on a particular type of interface

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T: ISomeInterface
{
}
```

---

After re-reading your question it sounds like you don't need a generic class at all here, it sounds like all you want is for `SomeClass` to implement `ISomeInterface` - in C# that's relatively straightforward to do. Firstly, define the interface

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    void Foo();
    Bar Bar();
}
```

Then define the class which is going to implement the interface

```
public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
{
    // SomeClass specific methods
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        ...
    }

    // implement ISomeInterface methods

    public void Foo()
    {
        ...
    }

    public Bar Bar()
    {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

So assuming `whatever` is of type `ISomeInterface` and you know it's an instance of `SomeClass` then your assignment would require a direct cast

```
SomeClass myVar = (SomeClass)whatever;
```

Or you could use the `as` operator for a safer conversion

```
SomeClass myVar = whatever as SomeClass;
if (myVar != null)
    // whatever was an instance of SomeClass
```

Comment: It is not clear to me that this is representing the same scenario

Comment: @MarcGravell to be honest, the more I read the question the more I think the OP really just needs `SomeClass` to implement `ISomeInterface`.

Comment: Wow go eat breakfast and this much feedback already :) Ideally yes its an implementation of the interface. The issue is, say i have 40 completly different sets of interfaces. The fact that they are from this class that auto populates itself is an unrelated thing. It doesn't make sense to couple these normally. The purpose of the objective-c syntax is that you can be assured that the object can do both of those, rather then having to check and cast each type seperatly. I think from the sounds of it I just need to use one of the techniques here or create interfaces for every scenario.

Comment: @user2292539 if you have 40 different interfaces, then yes `SomeClass` would need to implement all 40 of those interfaces if the end goal was to cast `SomeInterface` back to `SomeClass`. The question is though, why bother assigning `whatever` back to `SomeClass<T>` at all? Is it being passed to another service/method that expects `SomeClass`?

Comment: So that the factory can give people things that combine 2 seperate functionalities that are not always paired together.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in objectice c, this syntax is *structual* mapping; C# *does not have that*: you would need each type to explicitly declare that they implement the interface, i.e.

```
class SomeClass : SomeInterface
{
}
```

However, in purely C# terms:

If the C# `SomeClass` type implements `SomeInterface` implicitly (on the public interface), you can just use the methods directly, so I assume it is **either** the *subtype* that implements the interface, or that there is an explicit interface implementation (i.e. non-public API). In which case, various options:

- two variables:

  ```
  SomeClass myVar = whatever;
  SomeInterface myVarAsSomeInterface = (SomeInterface)whatever;
  ```

  then just access extra methods off `myVarAsSomeInterface.Foo();`
- inline cast:

  ```
  ((SomeInterface)myVar).Foo();
  ```
- generics and extension methods:

  ```
  public static void Foo<T>(this T obj) where T : SomeClass, SomeInterface
  {
      obj.Foo(); // should resolve to SomeInterface.Foo
  }
  ```

  or if you can't assume the interface because your won't know about the sub-type at compile-time:

  ```
  public static void Foo(this SomeClass obj)
  {
      ((SomeInterface)obj).Foo();
  }
  ```

Comment: Is there anything stylistically wrong with an extension method `AsSomeInterface` that returns the cast object? That would help avoid adding an extension method for every single member of `SomeInterface`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper only that it would be simpler and more appropriate to do a cast

Comment: Because the base class has nothing to do with the interface, and so it shouldn't know anything about it. At least in the original way this is setup. Its the person who is returning this object that is the one that knows, hey this is an object of type A, and by the way it can also handle job B from the interface.

Comment: @user2292539 yeah, that's a fundamental difference between C# (declared interfaces) and objective-c (which sounds like structural interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

The type of the variable would have to implement all required interfaces and inherit from the correct parent type. C# only supports inheriting from a single parent type but you can implement as many interfaces as you like.

With this in mind, you are correct that you would have to create a new type that satisfies your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I can think 2 ways to "....perform the unrelated tasks defined in SomeInterface."

Either you can inherit SomeClass with SomeInterface or you can use Composition and use SomeInterface as a property in SomeClass.